# VS2010 Find and Replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I need help using regular expressions using Find and Replace in VS2010. I want to
Find `request("somevar")` and replace it with `html_encode(request("somevar"))`

`somevar` will be a different for each `request("")`

Answer (score 3):

Replace `request({:q})` with `html_encode(request(\1))`.

Comment: using request({:q}) in the search box. I received an error. "The following text was not found."

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.